# How to solve System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, wcf-configuration, asynchronous-wcf-call

I'm developing a WebSite with average 50,000 visit(around 140,000 page views) in a day.
I'm using `WCF` as my services with `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall`
Also, I'm using async methods to call WCF services, 
Recently I get the following exception messages on some pages and on some requests:

```
Exception Type: System.ServiceModel.ServerTooBusyException
Exception Message: The HTTP service located at http://localhost:8090/SmartService.svc is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again later.
Stack Trace:    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Smartiz.ClientServices.ContentService.<GetContentsByIdsAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Smartiz.UI.Controllers.CompareController.<FillRequiredFields>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Smartiz.UI.Controllers.CompareController.<GetDevices>d__4b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Smartiz.UI.Controllers.CompareController.<Index>d__73.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)

        =========== Inner Exception ===========
        Exception Type: System.Net.WebException
        Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
```

Is it OK to change `serviceBehaviors` as the following?
 
Is the following a good solution?

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Smartiz.WcfService.SmartService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Smartiz.WcfService.ISmartService" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpsBinding" />
      <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I mean `serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2147483647" maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" maxConcurrentSessions="2147483647"`

Comment: Increasing the concurrent call is well and good but it may only delay the inevitable.  What sort of operations is your WCF service performing?  I see you are using `async` to call it.  However, if your service then performs any other I/O they should be `async` too. e.g. database; file etc

Comment: did  you use ***serviceThrottling*** and working ? did you improvements about performnance `WCF Service` and `IIS Sever` ?

Answer (score 2):

Check first if the App Pool is fine.
If your application produces too much exceptions in a time period you would get the same error message.

In my experience often - if the relevant properties `maxConcurrentInstances` and `maxConcurrentSessions` are correctly set like here - it is something faulty in the web.config when this error occures.

Comment: @mohammad-dayyan it would be easier to catch all Exceptions at a central spot. There are two important Interfaces to that: ```IErrorHandler``` and ```IServiceBehavior```. Take a look on that and check if there is any exception unhandled.
If no, then we have to take a look deeper. Sometimes WCF loads your config not completely and some Bindings are missing in runtime. Then it is senseless to discuss about the config if the loading fails ;-)